# Unique In Order

Tags: python, python-3.x

So the code can pass all the tests of Codewars but when I attempt an index error appears indicating there is a string index out of range, so i dont know if I have to break the loop at some point or how could I fix this? Thank you for everyones help.

```
    def unique_in_order(iterable):
        if iterable == None:
            return None
        if iterable == []:
            return []
        result = []
        i = 0
        while i < len(iterable)-1:
            if iterable[i] == iterable[i+1]:
                i += 1
                continue
            result.append(iterable[i])
            i += 1
        result.append(iterable[i])
        return result
```

```
 STDERR
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    test.assert_equals(unique_in_order(''),[])
  File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 14, in unique_in_order
    result.append(iterable[i])
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cover the case of `[]` but you do not cover `''`. Just add an if statement like the others and it should be ok:

```
if iterable == '':
    return ''
```

Comment: I would consider a more general `if len(iterable) == 0: return iterable` in case of other types. If we don't know what kind of iterable the function receives, this would be the most robust check.

Comment: That is a good idea. But it should also be noted that `len(None)` and similar objects would raise a TypeError, so it should be enclosed by a try block.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this as an alternative to your code (beginning of the function).
`if not iterable : return list(iterable)`